# Importing Hortonworks DockerSandbox

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

Good day, After installing and importing  Hortonworks DockerSandbox2.5, I tried to switch ON the Hortonworks DockerSandBox.

Comment: Congratulations on the install. What is your question?

Comment: After installation and import, then I tried to ON  the button but I got below feedback :                                                                                 
              CONNECTIVITY ISSUES DETECTED!                                             
              CHECK CONNECTION OF NETWORK INTERFACE                    
               FOR DETAILS, SEE VM SETUP INSTRUCTIONS.                 
              Please, what do I do next?                                                           
              Thanks

Comment: Comments aren't for the question. Please use the EDIT button to add this information to your question and make it better.